# Trying to tag another user in Discord Bot, but my string won't complete using discord.py

Tags: python, bots, discord.py

Friends, I am attempting to make a bot that when I use a command followed by mentioning another user, the bot will create a response that starts by tagging me, followed by a response, followed by tagging the user i originally mentioned.

So far, I have successfully created a string that has the first 2 parameters working, but i can't figure out how to have the bot tag a user that i mention. I have tried a number of different strings, but none of them seem to work.

Here is an example of the code as it is working so far (without the mentioning of another tagged user):

```
import asyncio
import random

from discord import user
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

BOT_PREFIX = ("=", "!!")
TOKEN = "#####################################"

client = Bot(command_prefix=BOT_PREFIX)


@client.command(name='uppercut')
@asyncio.coroutine
async def uppercut(ctx):
    possible_responses = [
        'has delivered a jaw shattering uppercut to'
    ]
    await ctx.send(ctx.message.author.mention + ", " + random.choice(possible_responses))


client.run(TOKEN)
```

---

Any suggestions anyone might have to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want the command to accept another parameter and to use a Member or User converter for that parameter. Then, you can just use the `mention` attribute of the Member or User object that's passed as that parameter.

For example:

```py
import discord

@client.command()
async def uppercut(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    possible_responses = [
        'has delivered a jaw shattering uppercut to'
    ]
    response = random.choice(possible_responses)
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.message.author.mention} {response} {member.mention}")
```

See https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#discord-converters for more information about Discord converters.

Alternatively, you can the [`mentions` attribute of the Message object](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.mentions) that you have from `Context.message`, which will give you a list of Member/User objects, representing the ones that were mentioned in the message.

For example:

```py
@client.command()
async def uppercut(ctx):
    possible_responses = [
        'has delivered a jaw shattering uppercut to'
    ]
    response = random.choice(possible_responses)
    mentioned = ctx.message.mentions[0]
    # Note, this does not necessarily retrieve the first Member/User mentioned
    # and errors if the message has no mentions
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.message.author.mention} {response} {mentioned.mention}")
```

Also, there's no need to use the `@asyncio.coroutine` decorator when you're already defining it with `async def`. In fact, [`@asyncio.coroutine` is deprecated in Python 3.8, and `async def` should be used instead](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.coroutine).

You also don't need to specify the name of the command explicitly if it's the same as your function name. See https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.command.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! Being a complete noob, how would I include that in operation? I am just feeling a little lost.

Comment: I've added some examples based on what you have so far.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try this out. I appreciate this more than I can say!